# mysqldump is ignoring option '--databases' due to invalid value

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have this MySQL database named `capsule_corporation_database`.

Then, I have this my.cnf file in my home directory:

## ~/.my.cnf

```
[client]
host=localhost
user=trunks
password=mai
database=capsule_corporation_database
```

### Attempt to mysqldump

```
mysqldump > copy_of_capsule_corporation_database.sql
```

The backup did not pursue and logged the below message:

```
Warning: mysqldump: ignoring option '--databases' due to invalid value 'capsule_corporation_database'
```

What does it mean and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix this issue, just move the database parameter from client to mysql in my .cnf

i.e

```
$ cat ~/.my.cnf
[client]
host=localhost
user=trunks
password=mai

[mysql]
database=capsule_corporation_database
```

Comment: A great explanation of this is given here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978990/getting-warning-ignoring-option-databases-due-to-invalid-value-testdatabase